# String comparison fails because of value passed by datatable, codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, datatables, codeigniter-2

I am facing a really strange problem which i am debugging from past 2 hours but unable to find the solution. Before explaining the problem, let me show the code

My Controller Function is

```
  $this->load->library('datatables');
    $actionLinkBar = $this->load->view("content/updates/dt_files/action_bar", array(), TRUE);
    $this->datatables
            ->select("id, name, status")
            ->where('id', $this->session_data['user_id'])
            ->from("t_user")
            ->add_column("action", $actionLinkBar, 'id, name, status');

    echo $this->datatables->generate();
```

And the code in my action_bar view is

```
    <?php
     $status_rec = '$3';
     var_dump($status_rec); // STRANGE OUTPUT -  string(2) "1" 
     ?>

 <div class="action_bar" data-update-id="<?php echo '$1'; ?>">

    <?php if ($status_rec == '1') { ?> // HENCE COMPARISON ALWAYS FAILS

         <span>Present</span>

    <?php }else { ?>

         <span>Absent</span> 

     <?php } ?>

 </div>
```

Now explaining the problem.. I am using Datatables with Codeigniter. I have a view template `action_bar` which will be displayed in one of the columns of datable in front end. The view has if/else condition based on value of `status` field from DB. If `status` feild value = 1 = Present. Else it is Absent. But though the `$status_rec` has value as '1' it still fails in comparison. Strange thing is on var_dumping `$status_rec`, i found that though it has proper value, the length is weird(2) though its single int. I even tried trimming etc but still no effect. Maybe that's why the comparison is failing. Your help is really needed :/

P.S - The DB feild that holds this value is int with length 1

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar problem solved it a bit by changing the library:

[Datatables.php with if condition](http://yadi.sk/d/_PbNC-vpNosbf)

changes in the *194, 196* and *440* strings

**How to use:**

```
$if = array('0' => array('if_condition'=>'$3', 'if_condition_eqv'=>'1', 'if_true'=>'<span>Present</span></div>', 'if_false'=>'<span>Absent</span></div>'));
$this->datatables->add_column("action", '<div class="action_bar" data-update-id="$1">', 'id, name, status');
```

**BUT you have to change:** ".=" On "=" (strings *497* and *504*)

Should work.

I would really appreciate if someone will correct code

P.S. Sorry for my english